# Unable to insert row - columns missing on data table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I am having trouble getting up and going with Laravel. The database (MySQL) is giving me some errors, but I am uncertain how to go about fixing them. I wrote this simple migration to create a songs table.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSongsTable extends Migration
{
    // Run the migrations.
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('songs', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title'); /* <- Here is the title column */
            $table->text('lyrics')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    // Reverse the migrations.
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('songs');
    }
}
```

Then I migrate it and everything seems to be working fine.

```
$ php artisan migrate
Migrated: 2015_07_14_150540_create_songs_table
```

But when I try to insert something an error shows up.  It says that I am missing the title column, but at far as I can see in my code above, I should have one, and I get no errors otherwise.

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.5.1 (PHP 5.5.24 — cli) by Justin Hileman

>>> DB::table('songs')->insert([ 'title' => 'Fall',
'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime]);

Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]:
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'title' in 'field list'
(SQL: insert into `songs` (`title`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
values (Fall, 2015-07-14 15:14:10, 2015-07-14 15:14:10))'
```

Edit: Looking at the database in phpMyAdmin, The table is there, but the title column is missing. Here is what I get:
[image: table detail]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your phpadmin to confirm the table is there?

Comment: `created_at` and `updated_at` should be inserted/updated automaticly. So you don't have to insert them manually.

Comment: @ChrisTownsend Thanks. Good point. Info added.

Comment: @PKeidel Thanks for the tip. I'll keep that in mind. The problem still stands though

Comment: Can you run a php artisan migrate:refresh and recheck the table please

Comment: What do you wanted to show us after `Here is what I get:` right at the end?

Comment: @ChrisTownsend. That worked. Thank you. I am not sure what is different today from yesterday, as  i had run a migrate and migrate:rollback without success, but today it seems to be working. I'll keep my eye on it, but it is all fine for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Table hasn't been migrated into the database.

Please use

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

to reinstate your table

Comment: Is there anything that `migrate:refresh` does that doing a `migrate:rollback` and `migrage` would not do?